# Getting timeout error while trying to download offline region in Mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

Timeout error is thrown every time when I try to download an offline area.

The reference for my implementation is in the following link below:
[Link to offline manager](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/offline/OfflineManagerActivity.java)

Also the "onError(OfflineRegionError error)" method from the observer  keeps on getting called multiple times.

The downloading used to happen without any issues sometimes ago. No code changes have been made. This happens both in mapbox versions 4.2.1 and 6.5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue may occur when there is sudden drop in network (network interruption) also - so you have to check network once when this error comes and handle accordingly.

Comment: Also the zoom level of the download area has to decreased to avoid the error.